# Stop Scrapy Spider Running in a Cron Job

Tags: python, cron, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a Scrapy Spider which I have scheduled as a Cron Job.
I am using the -o option in order to write my data to a csv file.

```
scrapy crawl my_spider -o my_csv.csv
```

I am utilizing Crawlera, but I am out of requests. I seek to shutdown my spider and have the output written to csv. Scrapy has not yet written the output to csv and I am worried that if I kill the process, the data will be lost.

Is there a way to gracefully shutdown a spider, running as a cron job, without having to wait for the crawl to 'finish'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I am afraid your scraper has not run at all, otherwise you would have seen some data into output CSV, because scrapy writes data simultaneous in CSV, not when scrapy process finishes.

Anyways, if its running, please read below.

Run `ps -aux | grep scrapy` and find PID of scrapy process

Just send `kill PID` only ONCE and it will gracefully shutdown

NOTE:

Do not send `kill PID` more than once, otherwise your process will get KILLED without completing remaining requests

Comment: The spider is running. I can see the process and actively view the logs.

Comment: I used kill and the process stopped immediately, wrote data to the csv.